# mysql join 2 tables and count all rows from each table

Tags: mysql, join, count

I have table contracts c (id, exp_date) and table members m (id, cid).
I need to count all contracts and all members together joining the 2 tables on m.cid = c.id.

I tried this but obviously isn't not right as it returns a same count result from both tables

```
SELECT count(m.id) as totmembers , count(c.id) as totcontracts
from members m
join contracts c on m.cid = c.id
where DATEDIFF(c.im_exp, CURDATE()) > 0
```

Results should be something like 5000 contracts, 12.000 members but i'm getting 12.000 for both totmembers and totcontracts.

Comment: Do you want a total `count()` on both fields, or `count(distinct)` on them?

Comment: @vyegorov: I want a total count

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT count(m.id) as totmembers , count(distinct c.id) as totcontracts
from members m
join contracts c on m.cid = c.id
where DATEDIFF(c.im_exp, CURDATE()) > 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Becouse you are created an INNER JOIN statement. Create a new query with two individual query int the SELECT list.

```
SELECT (SELECT ... WHERE ...) AS totmembers, (SELECT ... WHERE ...) AS totcontracts
```

Comment: In order for the where to work in the 2nd sub-query I need to join table members to table contracts.

Comment: It's true, do it individualy in the 2 subquery.

Comment: You mean like this? Dont think it will work...
SELECT (COUNT(*) from aitisi a WHERE a.im_exp>CURRENT_DATE) AS totcontracts, 
(SELECT count(*) from members m join aitisi a on a.id = m.symbid where DATEDIFF(a.im_exp, CURDATE()) > 0) AS totmembers